# Difference between initializing TypeScript variables in the class itself and doing it in the constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class cls {
    str= 'hello';
}
```

vs

```
class cls {
    str: string;
    constructor() {
        this.str = 'hello';
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these two forms?

Comment: The first one works with a default constructor that calls `super()` as well, other than that there's no difference.

Comment: I've removed the ES6 tag since neither of your snippets is valid ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. This:

```
class Foo {
    str = 'hello';
}

class Bar {
    str: string;
    constructor() {
        this.str = 'hello';
    }
}
```

will result in the following output:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.str = 'hello';
    }
    return Foo;
}());
var Bar = (function () {
    function Bar() {
        this.str = 'hello';
    }
    return Bar;
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific difference here.But if you write below:

```
class cls {
str: string;
constructor(string str) {
    this.str = str;
}
```

then on the time initialise of class you can assign the value to property.
For example :

```
var obj1= new cls("obj1");
var obj2= new cls("obj2");
```

This won't possible with your first case.

Answer (score -1):

When you choose to initialize variables in constructor it gives you an additional benefit of initializing those values at the time of object creation like this :

```
var obj1= new cls("obj1"); //Ability to change variable value
var obj2= new cls("obj2");
```

But when you do not initialize value in constructor, then you have to first create the object and then need to access that variable to change its value like this:

```
var obj1= new cls(); //Two step method to initialize one value
obj1.str = "New value";
```

So it is always better and standard way to initialize variables in constructor this is the benefit of using object oriented programming language.

Comment: `str` was not a constructor parameter, the answer therefore isn't applicable.